# Read ALL content of an RTF file including headers and footers

Tags: vb.net, rtf

I need to read the text content of RTF files including headers and footers. I am able to read the body text by loading the file into a Rich Text Box and using its Text property. But the RTB does not recognize headers and footers per posts I found on the internet.

So my question is, how can I read all text content from an RTF file.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

Do this when you open a file:

```
RichTextBox1.LoadFile(<file path>, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
```

Comment: I do this and use the RichTextBox1.Text to read the text. The problem is that it does not include the header text. From my research on the web I found that the RTB does not recognize the header. So using RTB is not going to work.

Comment: What header? Because it saves all colors, font sizes, aligns options etc. (I don't now much about RichText :) )

Comment: I am not an RTF expert but what I have learned is that there is a "header" for formatting. That is not what I am talking about. I am talking about a page header that contains text. If you open an RTF file in Word you can select to add headers and footers to the document. Those are what I am talking about.

Comment: Could this be something? http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?604231-Rich-Text-Box-With-Headers-And-Footer

Comment: I saw that posting but could not figure out how to find the code in the code bank. Can you tell me how to find it and download it? It does look promising.

Comment: Oh, one cannot download it: the upload is removed. :(. It seems like the headers and footers have something to do with Microsoft Office. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178795.aspx